# d3.js hover on map not displaying text box, css problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, d3.js

I've just started learning javascript and css and recently I've been playing around with d3.js. I'm trying to display a map of a state. The map is getting displayed. I've increased the line width of the district boundaries, but I couldn't do so for the outer boundary of the state.

Also, on move hover on each district of the state, I've been trying to a text box on the side, which is not happening. Mouse hover also changes the color of the district as well as the line width of the boundary. Why is the text box not appearing? Or is it appearing somewhere out of screen? Where am I going wrong and how do I fix these?

```
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
<script>
  var width = 500,
    height = 500;
  const projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .center([88.4, 27.5])
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(10000);
  const path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

  const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  const g = svg.append('g');

  d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shklnrj/IndiaStateTopojsonFiles/master/Sikkim.topojson')
    .then(state => {
      g.append('path')
        .datum({
          type: 'Sphere'
        })
        .attr('class', 'sphere')
        .attr('d', path);

      g.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.merge(state, state.objects.Sikkim.geometries))
        .attr('class', 'land')
        .attr('d', path);

      g.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(state, state.objects.Sikkim, (a, b) => a !== b))
        .attr('class', 'boundary')
        .attr('d', path);

      g.append("g")
        .attr("id", "dts")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(state, state.objects.Sikkim).features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        //.on("click", clicked)

        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select("h2").text(d.properties.Dist_Name);
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("fill", "yellow")
            .attr("opacity", 1);
          var prop = d.properties;

          var string = "<p><strong>District Code</strong>: " + prop.State_Code + "</p>";
          string += "<p><strong>Disctrict Name</strong>: " + prop.Dist_Name + "</p>";

          d3.select("#textbox")
            .html("")
            .append("text")
            .html(string)
        })

        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("fill", "deeppink")
        })

        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .attr("fill", "deeppink")

    });

</script>
```

Here is the css part:

```
    svg {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.land {
  fill: #ff1a75;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #00ffff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

h2 {
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.hover {
  fill: yellow;

}

#textbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 100px;
}

#textbox text p {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems the attribute**top** and **left** are making the problem
Here is a good example to show tooltip, and you can review the **div.tooltip** 
 in CSS section, https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `script` below `#textbox` element.

```css
svg {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.land {
  fill: #ff1a75;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #00ffff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

h2 {
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.hover {
  fill: yellow;
}

#textbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 100px;
}

#textbox text p {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>

<div id="textbox"></div>

<!-- move your JS code here -->
<script>
  var width = 500,
    height = 500;
  const projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .center([88.4, 27.5])
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(10000);
  const path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

  const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  const g = svg.append('g');

  d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shklnrj/IndiaStateTopojsonFiles/master/Sikkim.topojson')
    .then(state => {
      g.append('path')
        .datum({
          type: 'Sphere'
        })
        .attr('class', 'sphere')
        .attr('d', path);

      g.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.merge(state, state.objects.Sikkim.geometries))
        .attr('class', 'land')
        .attr('d', path);

      g.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(state, state.objects.Sikkim, (a, b) => a !== b))
        .attr('class', 'boundary')
        .attr('d', path);

      g.append("g")
        .attr("id", "dts")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(state, state.objects.Sikkim).features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        //.on("click", clicked)

        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select("h2").text(d.properties.Dist_Name);
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("fill", "yellow")
            .attr("opacity", 1);
          var prop = d.properties;

          var string = "<p><strong>District Code</strong>: " + prop.State_Code + "</p>";
          string += "<p><strong>Disctrict Name</strong>: " + prop.Dist_Name + "</p>";

          d3.select("#textbox")
            .html("")
            .append("text")
            .html(string)
        })

        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("fill", "deeppink")
        })

        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .attr("fill", "deeppink")

    });
</script>
```